# How to add multiple Standard SQL functions within JPQL

Tags: sql, spring-boot, jpql, sql-function

Is it possible to add multiple SQL functions within JPQL ? (Spring Boot application)

By using **MetadataBuilderContributor** I succeded to add only one.
Is there any way to add more ?

Current code:

```
public class SqlFunctionsMetadataBuilderContributor implements MetadataBuilderContributor {

    @Override
    public void contribute(MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder) {
        SQLFunction sqlFunction = new StandardSQLFunction("group_concat", StandardBasicTypes.STRING);
        metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction("group_concat", sqlFunction);
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.metadata_builder_contributor = com.bfp.configuration.strategies.SqlFunctionsMetadataBuilderContributor
```